# Trigger jquery function on tab load? None of my attempts are working

Tags: jquery, html

I am using the responsivematchheight jquery script to equalize divs in five different tabs.

The active tab works perfectly, but when I change the tab, the script does not fire. I've tried using onclick, activate, load... I'm sure I'm doing something wrong.

Here's the basic function for loading the script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('.tabfeature').responsiveEqualHeightGrid();
    });
```

And here's the block of html that triggers the different tabs:

```
<div class="tabshome">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="hometabs">
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#ps">Prospective Students</a>    </li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cs">Current Students</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#fs">Faculty/Staff</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#comm">Our Community</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#alum">Alumni</a></li>
</ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
<div id="ps" class="tab-pane fade in active">     
<?php if( have_rows('prospective_students') ): ?>

<?php while( have_rows('prospective_students') ): the_row(); 

    // vars
    $ps_photo = get_sub_field('ps_box_one_photo');
    $ps_title = get_sub_field('ps_box_one_title');
    $ps_text = get_sub_field('ps_box_one_text');
    $ps_link = get_sub_field('ps_box_one_link');
    $ps_linktext = get_sub_field('ps_box_one_link_text');
    ?>
<div class="tabholder">
    <div class="tabfeature">
```

I've tried all of the following (not all at once...):

```
jQuery("#hometabs a").click(function(responsiveEqualHeightGrid){
            jQuery('.tabfeature').responsiveEqualHeightGrid();

});
jQuery( "#hometabs" ).tabs();
 jQuery("#hometabs").tabs({
create: function(event, ui) {

    jQuery('.tabfeature').responsiveEqualHeightGrid();
}
});

jQuery( "#hometabs" ).on( "tabsload", function( event, ui ) {
jQuery('.tabfeature').responsiveEqualHeightGrid(); } );
```

Here's the page: http://tcmedc.wpengine.com

Am I using incorrect syntax or am I just totally off-base??

Comment: Did u write a jquery extension named "responsiveEqualHeightGrid"? Because u r using that function on jQuery Elements.

Comment: I'm using this: https://github.com/Sam152/Javascript-Equal-Height-Responsive-Rows

Answer (score 1):

You can define the load procedure right in the tabs constructor:

```js
$("#hometabs").tabs({
  load: function(event, ui){
    $('.tabfeature').responsiveEqualHeightGrid();
  }
  create: function(event, ui) {
    $('.tabfeature').responsiveEqualHeightGrid();
  }
});
```

But I don't think it will work as you expect. The API description at https://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-load describes an event which is triggered by an AJAX call after a remote tab has been loaded, for which you need to use this: https://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax. As far as I can tell, your tabs are pre-generated by the PHP script and the effect from responsiveEqualHeightGrid() which you see is actually coming from other places you trigger it.

If you just want to trigger on opening a new tab, you can use `activate:` trigger instead:

```js
$("#hometabs").tabs({
  activate: function(event, ui){
    $('.tabfeature').responsiveEqualHeightGrid();
  }
  create: function(event, ui) {
    $('.tabfeature').responsiveEqualHeightGrid();
  }
});
```

Activate does not get fired at creation, so you still need the `create:` directive. If activate does not suit you, you can use the href attribute in a tab’s link to select the appropriate tab on the link’s click event:

```js
$("#hometabs a").click(function() {
  $('.tabfeature').responsiveEqualHeightGrid();
  //OR to target specifically the tab you’re opening;
  $($(this).attr("href")).find(".tabfeature").responsiveEqualHeightGrid();
});
```

Comment: I believe I tried that - and you're right - it didn't work. There must be a way to trigger or update the function on click or on tab load, though, right??
ETA: Yes, the tabs are just hidden, but are pre-generated on page load.

Comment: @BlueTabby, if you want to just trigger on tab turning active, try using `activate: function(){}` you can also use $("#hometabs a").click(function() {}); where you use $($(this).attr("href")); The tab links are linked to individual tabs by the tabs’ ids being written in the link’s href, so you can use it as the ID to select your proper tab and apply your responsiveEqualHeightGrid() from there.

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain  - does $($(this).attr("href")); go inside the click function? And then I still need to call the responsive equal height function as well, yes? I'm going to play around with it now - but thought I'd ask for clarification in case I run into trouble - which is exceedingly likely... I feel like I've tried everything! :)

Comment: OK - so when I add this below my initial function:
 $("#hometabs a").click(function() {
 $($(this).attr("href"));
 $.fn.responsiveEqualHeightGrid._update() ;
  });
It just breaks the equal height even in the active loaded tab... sigh.
I also tried just repeating the original function call instead of the 
_update() - same thing.

Comment: Try doing this: `$("#hometabs a").click(function() {
  $('.tabfeature').responsiveEqualHeightGrid();});`
OR this: `$("#hometabs a").click(function() {
  $($(this).attr("href")).find(".tabfeature").responsiveEqualHeightGrid();
});` The first one would fire the responsiveEqualHeightGrid() on all tabs and the second one will fire it only on the tab you just clicked. To clarify how jquery works: `$(this).attr("href");` inside a click function on anchor tag will return the href property of the anchor, it's useless alone. I was only giving an example of how to use it as a selector filter.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - I found a solution - although I never found an answer!

But if anyone should run into this issue, I tried another jQuery plugin script called jquery-match-height.js (https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height) and it has handlers and triggers built in to handle events and changes on the page.

Works perfectly right out of the box! :)